# Need help with keyframe animation css3 in Moz (firefox 4)

Tags: html, animation, css

now that firefox 4 is out I want to get some of my sites that have a chrome animation, working in firefox. I have got all the simple animations working in firefox (rotate, movement etc), but don't know if it's possible to do keyframe animation like it is in chrome(webkit)?

An example of a chrome animation is below

```
@-webkit-keyframes "sway" {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
 25% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }
 50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }
 75% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }}
```

I animate this with "-webkit-animation-name: "sway" " . Simply changing all prefixes to moz doesn't help. Any info would be great.

Many thanks

Nick

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not yet support CSS Animations, follow [bug 435442](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435442) to track the development progress.  The bug is fairly active so I'd guess they're trying to get this into the next release.

Answer (score 0):

As robertc said, there are no css animations in Firefox yet, only transitions. If your animation is just a shaking box like you have in your css, you would achieve it easily chaining the transitions with a little bit of javascript...

Your css:

```
#yourdiv {
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

Your Javascript:

```
//onload body
var element = document.getElementById("yourdiv");
element.style.MozTransform = "rotate(2deg)";
element.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
    var rotate = (element.style.MozTransform == "rotate(2deg)") ? "rotate(-2deg)" : "rotate(2deg)";
    element.style.MozTransform = rotate;
}, false);
```

I haven't actually tested it in Firefox, but here's a working version for webkit:

http://jsfiddle.net/J6SMb/